# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

For the following code, I am getting the following error.  I don't know how to work around this.  How can I call `volumeCheck()` upon the button click?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var player = AVAudioPlayer()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.volumeCheck()
            }) {
                Text("Click to test chimes volume")
            }
        }
    }

    mutating func volumeCheck() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(
            forResource: "chimes",
            withExtension: "mp3"
            ) else { return }

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.volume = Float(self.sliderValue)
            player.play()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        print("volume checked print")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try making player an @State variable.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that `View` is a `struct` and it's `body` field is a computed property with a **nonmutating** getter. In your code it happens **mutating** method to be called in that nonmutating getter. So all you need to do is put your player to some kind of model:

```swift
class Model {
    var player: AVPlayerPlayer()
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var model = Model()

    // player can be changed from anywhere
}
```

P.S. In some other cases you may want changes in your model be reflected in view so you'd have to add @ObservedObject just before model declaration.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set player to a new object in volumeCheck(). Set the player in your initialiser:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    private var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    public init() {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "chimes",
                                     withExtension: "mp3") {
            self.player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Click to test chimes volume") {
                self.volumeCheck()
                }   .disabled(player == nil)
        }
    }

    private func volumeCheck() {
        player?.prepareToPlay()
        player?.volume = Float(self.sliderValue)
        player?.play()
        print("volume checked print")
    }
}
```

Please note that you are using sliderValue in your code even though it is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score -2):

Just a little gist: (for others.. arriving here like me... )

https://gist.github.com/ingconti/e0a2ceaf243ff2e27ed02144e506d996

the logic is to use @State:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    //var msg = ""      // WRONG! try to uncomment..
    @State var msg = "" // CORRECT!

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(msg)
            Button("Fill me!", action: {
                fillMe()
            })
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func fillMe(){
        self.msg = "Hello!!"
    }
}
```

Hope can help others.